# How to make a fade effect on the Unity's scrollView?

Tags: unity, gui, scrolling

I have a basic `ScrollView`, with some additional scripts so it snaps to the nearest element (focusing on it).

When I perform the scroll, it looks like this:
[image]

What I need to achieve is to fade the part which is currently going off the screen.

Like when I'm scrolling left, the right panel is coming in, and the left one - fading out:

[image]

Is there any built-in option for this? I'm opened for any ideas!

Comment: AFAIK there isn't any in-built function for this in Unity. What you can do, however, is use an [Mask](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Mask.html) on top of the scroll view with the same transparency you want on the scroll view (faded out in sideways in your case, I think).

Comment: Unfortunately, Mask only removes "where a sibling Graphic would write 0 to the stencil buffer." You can make a shape with it, but not a gradient.

Comment: @Spectre, do you prefer to fade an entire area (as in your second image), or to fade the edge of the area as it reaches the edge of the screen?

Comment: Of course edge would be nicer, but also harder to implement, cause I would need to fade a part of the object ;/